# "___" has not been registered. This can happen if: "Metro(the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors

I worked with a project called "Scooter" in Visual Studio Code. Then I switched to another application and when I tried to run it with "npm run android", the following error appeared: ""Scooter" has not been registered. This can happen if: "Metro(the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder". I tried various ways, but my problem was not solved. By the way, I had previously loaded the project I was running on the D disk and pulled it from there (I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but). I am writing using translation, I apologize if there is any mistake.

I would be very happy if anyone has any suggestions or advice.

Comment: I assume you checked that you've run the command in the right folder after you switched to the second project, right?

Comment: @dianaqqq Yes, I checked. I ran it in the correct folder.

Comment: Ok, I would try a few things: 1. Make sure you stopped the other metro, which was running in the other folder. 2. Run `adb devices` to see the available devices; Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and then try to start the metro with `npm run start` and build the app from Android Studio directly